# Windows Keybord display

Tags: c++, input, keyboard, overlay, on-screen-keyboard

I am trying to make an on screen keyboard for windows in C++ that rather than sends an input such as SendInput() takes intercepts the user inputs allowing the user to use a window and have the key press show on the on-screen keyboard.

I plan on using this as a way of making tutorials in programs such as unity and can be used as an overlay for people know play games. to do this I will need to take in the input without stopping it going to its destination but I don't know how.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What is the question that you are asking, what have you tried so far, what problems/errors do you have? include any code samples that could help.

Comment: i have tried kernel patching but I don't want to have to have to patch any drivers, I was thinking of using a windows hook as it seems like an easy way to do this but i have never used them so i don't know how it will turn out